# Bootable USB does not work

Tags: boot, usb, usb-flash-drive, unetbootin

I tried to install Windows 7 on a bootable USB. 
It was successful and it told me to reboot now. I clicked it and then it rebooted, and when I selected the USB on boot, this happened:

When I opened it, it said UNETBOOTIN as the heading and the option only was default.
I clicked on default and nothing happened.
There was also a countdown: Automatic boot in 10,9........0 and then the countdown restarted and restarted continuously while nothing was happening.
There was also an option to press Tab. When I pressed it something was written like unetinit something like that.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Probably a useless comment, but: I had the same thing, and I fixed it. Unfortunately I cannot remember how, but at least we know it's fixable.

Comment: But how to fix it??

Comment: i tested it with Mobalivecd still the same problem

Comment: It might help if you described the behavior more clearly.  Did "nothing" happen, or was there a restarting countdown?  What, exactly, was the error message?  etc.

Comment: nothing happened and both the restarting countdown happened

Comment: and there was no error message

Comment: Unetbootin is specifically for Linux distributions. It won't work if you try and create a Windows liveUSB.

Comment: Can you please clarify your question? Do you want to install Windows **onto** the USB drive itself? Or do you want to install Windows onto a computer using the USB as the installation media?

Answer (score 3):

Unetbootin is designed specifically for Linux distributions and will not work if you are trying to create a Live Windows USB.

You can use an application called [WinToUSB](http://www.easyuefi.com/wintousb/) to achieve this. However, you will need to have access to a Windows computer to start the installation process.

Comment: you may want to comment on karel's answer then saying he's wrong (karel not karen).  Karel wrote "I fixed the same UNetbootin countdown error by reformatting the USB drive to FAT32 and then trying the same way as before with UNetbootin."   <--- so since you disagree, you may want to address his answer in the comments section

Comment: @barlop Or we could downvote an answer that is wrong, and upvote the answers that are right!

Comment: You shouldn't just downvote, without a comment as to why, especially when it's not obvious. It's not obvious unless somebody has done it and seen the error. Even your first sentence you should realize,stating "why" his answer doesn't work,. is not a technical explanation.  It may well be that it doesn't work but your "why" is a cover up of a technical reason that you don't know or haven't written.. Your statement has the pretence of being a reason and is very untechical, and it's a technical question.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed the same UNetbootin countdown error by reformatting the USB drive to FAT32 and then trying the same way as before with UNetbootin.

Answer (score 1):

If you simply want to create a USB-based installer, just use [Rufus](http://rufus.akeo.ie):

[image: 1]

Comment: The user wants to install Windows onto the USB drive, not from the USB drive. That being said, Windows To Go is a feature that would work if the asker wanted Windows 8 or 10.

Comment: Actually I'm not sure *what* he wants to do, hence my *if...* above. From his previous question seems like he was trying to create an installer for XP first, and now for Win7? Does he actually want to create a Windows LiveUSB using WinPE? (Frankly given his comments so far I am not sure what he'd even do with one.) I think he needs to confirm or else his questions might be closed for lack of clarity.

Comment: Good point. I was taking his first statement literally. But it's probably not that clear cut...